# Exclude Audience from Particular Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is their a way to exclude audiences using Exclusion Script in user initiated emails? For example I have sent an email on 10/1 and now I am sending same email again but I want to exclude anyone who have open my email on 10/1?
I am specifically looking for any exclusion script. Don't want to create query activity or measures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find out who opened your previous send, you would need a query or measure to place them into a data extension to be looked up by the exclusion script. It simply isn't possible without either of these options.

I would look up the jobid of your send (can be found in tracking tab) and do something like this:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM _Open
WHERE JobID = '123456' /* Replace with your JobID */

/* Target: yourExclusionDE */
```

You then could use this DE as an exclusion list in the Send (while selecting audience) or via an exclusion Script.

Something like:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("yourExclusionDE", "SubscriberKey", AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")))> 0
```

This will exclude any subscribers that exist inside your Exclusion DE that you created.

Technically you could do the lookup in the exclusion script on the `_Open` Dataview, but this would be heavily resource intensive and likely cause the whole send to error and time out .